# How can I use the objects ConnectionStringSettings and ConfigurationManager into my C# - NUNIT project?

Tags: c#, nunit, connection-string

I'm trying to apply the solution proposed in this question: [Using the connectionstring in an nunit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164251/using-the-connectionstring-in-an-nunit-test) but I can't seem to find the `ConnectionStringSettings` and `ConfigurationManager` objects in the new Framework 4.5.

I added the namespace: `System.Configuration`. Where acording [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.aspx) is supposed to be. But Visual Studio still cant find it.

Could anyone here give me a hand with this?

Comment: Have you added the reference to `System.Configuration` to your project?

Comment: ThankYou that was what I was missing. I though if I didnt have the reference in my project i would gave me an error when I added the namespace. Can I add a namespace without having a reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add reference to `System.Configuration` to your project..

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to System.configuration to your project and use that dll in files